# Change percentage range qtm-generated map

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, ggmap, r-maptools

I am checking [qtm helpfiles](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tmap/vignettes/tmap-nutshell.html), but it doesn't say how to change legend percentage.

```
library(ggmap)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(maptools)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tmap)

doe <- readOGR(dsn = ".", layer = "doesep")
qtm(doe, fill = "sep12_PERC", fill.title = "Installs")
```

This line `qtm(doe, fill = "sep12_PERC", fill.title = "Installs")` creates this map, but we would like Installs to be

```
0 to 24
25 to 49
50 to 74
75 to 100
```

[image]

How to approach this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using funcion `qtm()` then you should add argument `fill.style="fixed"` to use your own fill scale and with argument `fill.breaks=` add break points.

```
qtm(doe, fill = "sep12_PERC", fill.title = "Installs",
                 fill.style="fixed",fill.breaks=c(0,25,50,75,100))
```